# ProFTPD AuthOrder inside VirtualHost is being ignored

Tags: proftpd

I am trying to configure proftpd 1.3.5b. 
What I would like to achieve is simple: only one VirtualHost, users will log in based on AuthUserFile and not based on /etc/passwd.

The problem is that all the authentication related configuration inside a VirtualHost is being ignored (although the VirtualHost is being loaded successfully).

Here is my config:

```
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.162>
......
        DefaultRoot             /disk/ftp/
        AuthOrder mod_auth_file.c
        AuthUserFile                    /etc/proftpd/misc/ftp.users
        AuthGroupFile                   /etc/proftpd/misc/ftp.group
....
</VirtualHost>
```

Users can successfully login based on /etc/passwd and ftp.users is being ignored.
DefaultRoot is also ignored.

If I place everything in proftpd.conf, outside the virtualhost, is working.
According to documentation, AuthOrder & AuthUserFile is supported inside VirtualHost directive:
http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_AuthUserFile.html

Any idea what is causing this problem?
Best Regards

Comment: What IP address/DNS name are your clients using to connect to your FTP server?

Comment: They are using a hostname, ftp.mydomain.com, that resolves to IP 10.11.12.162

Comment: Hmm.  What happens if you use `SocketBindTight on`?  The behavior you describe usually happens when the client connects to an IP/port different from your `<VirtualHost>`, _or_ when the default "server config" server is already listening on that IP/port.

Comment: Yes, probably this is the case. <VirtualHost 10.11.12.162> is totally ignored. Even ServerName is displayed from the proftpd.conf instead of the VirtualHost!

Comment: proftpd is behind a NAT. The public IP is resolving to a DNS name and receiving connections from public IPs. <VirtualHost ftp.mydomain.com> is not working. And ServerAlias is not implemented: fatal: ServerAlias: not yet implemented

Answer (score 0):

Reviving this necro post to mention that we had the same issue when we tried to do the exact same thing.

Adding `AuthPAM off` inside the VirtualHost fixed our problem.